# how to install latest version of php 5.3.10 in centos 6?

Tags: centos

i want to install joomla 3.6 latest version but my host needs to use PHP 5.3.10 or higher to run this version of Joomla!

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention whether this was your own server or whether you were using a hosting company. If you are using a hosting company, you should contact them. One shared hosting servers it is common for the hosting company to have several php versions from which to choose. This is normally done by using a directive in the .htaccess file for the domain.

If you are using a vps or dedicated server, the hosting company should be able to provide you directions on how to upgrade the php version or they may even be able to upgrade it for you.

If you are running your own server, a quick Google search will provide a link to the Centos site with instructions on how to upgrade.  However if you are using something like cPanel, be aware that cPanel is rather particular about the php versions installed and their locations. We would need more information in that case.